# Windows 7 administrator and still need to "Run as administrator"

Tags: windows-7, administrator

I'm having a mystery.
I have a Windows 7 PC, I am an administrator on it. But, I have a software tool that still requires me to run it with "Run as Administrator" to work properly. Why isn't it enough just to be the admin and just run it with double-click?

The thing gets complicated - I have another PC with a user that is an administrator also, and the tool runs there just with double-click properly.
What could be the difference between the PCs? In both of them, the user is an administrator!

Thanks for any help,

Comment: Not a programming question. Better suited to superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

This is the impact of the [User Account control](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/00d04415-2b2f-422c-b70e-b18ff918c281) (UAC), which assigned 2 tokens to admin accounts and runs the shell (explorer) and all started programs by default with the filtered token which represents standard user rights. To request admin rights, you have to right click and select “Run as administrator”.